# How to relate two integration contour?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, advice

How one can relate two integration contour? For example if I have an integration contour like $\int_{-a}^{a}f(x)dx$ here let say a=infinity. How I can say that the integral $\int_{2}^{3}f(x)dx$ is a part of the first integral or in other words that the integration contour of the second integral is the subset of the integration contour of the first integral.

Comment: $[2,3]\subset[-a,a]$.